# How to apply css for html page in Iframe?

Tags: css, pdf, iframe, adobe

I've a DIV, inside that i've Iframe. In that Iframe i'm loading the Html page. So I want to apply the css for that Html page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Keep in mind that this does not work cross-domain, meaning you can't change another person's website

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the style inside the Iframe... It is no possible, when you show an Iframe you can't modify his style.

If yu create the Iframe, apply the style  modification before to show in any page